QGIS Export to PDF not clipping my map
I have a map that I have created a layout for that I am very happy with however when I go to export it to PDF so I can have it printed the actual map part is no longer clipped correctly and I get part of it extending beyond the bounds I had set, see screenshots below.
Layout:

Exported PDF:

I have also noticed that the colours and line sizes are not in line with what the QGIS Layout manager shows, though this is less of an issue than the clipping.

Nice. For the line width, you probably need to check how they are set in the layer or gris styles (points,map units, ...), and possibly play with the values. Results will differ, also based on the export resolution/ppi. For the non clipped map background, can you share a screenshot of how your map layout is set ? Do you have all layers clicked in the Map item Clipping settings?

Please specify the exact QGIS version used.

Had issues in the past - RAM was an issue. After doubling the RAM no issues.
